# Joining 2 data frames with overlapping data

Tags: python, join, pandas

I have 2 data frames created by pivot tables

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'axis1': ['Unix','Window','Apple','Linux'],
                 'A': [1,np.nan,1,1],
                 'B': [1,np.nan,np.nan,1],
                 'C': [np.nan,1,np.nan,1],
                 'D': [1,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                 }).set_index(['axis1'])

print (df)

df2=pd.DataFrame({'axis1': ['Unix','Window','Apple','Linux','A'],
                 'A': [1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                 'E': [1,np.nan,1,1,1],
                 }).set_index(['axis1'])
print (df2)
```

Output looks like this

```
         A   B   C   D
axis1                 
Unix     1   1 NaN   1
Window NaN NaN   1 NaN
Apple    1 NaN NaN   1
Linux    1   1   1 NaN

[4 rows x 4 columns]
         A   E
axis1         
Unix     1   1
Window   1 NaN
Apple  NaN   1
Linux  NaN   1
A      NaN   1
```

Lets say I want to combine them but I want only want values of 1
So far I got it but it does not have column E or row A:

```
>>> df.update(df2)
>>> df
        A   B   C   D
axis1                
Unix    1   1 NaN   1
Window  1 NaN   1 NaN
Apple   1 NaN NaN   1
Linux   1   1   1 NaN

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

How would I update it to get the additional axis values? (include row A and Column E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) your first Dataframe before you call update

one robust way would be to calculate the union of both columns and rows of both df, maybe there is a smarter way, but I can't think of any at the moment

```
df = df.reindex(columns=df2.columns.union(df.columns),
                index=df2.index.union(df.index))
```

then you call update on that, and it should work.